# Execute linux command and store output in a file android

Tags: android, linux

I would like to execute 'top -n 1' command using android and store the output of top command in a file in the internal storage in my device, if possible. Otherwise the file should be stored in sd card. I used the following code to achieve it.

```
File logFile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"logtex.txt");
            if(!logFile.exists())
            {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            }

            logFile.setExecutable(true,false);
            logFile.setReadable(true,false);
            logFile.setWritable(true,false);
            Log.e("executeToplog", "err in");
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 > /data/user/0/com.example.abcdef.memcpuusage/files/logtex.txt ");
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What changes should be made to the code?

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` is not helpful. What is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: after running the program, logtex.txt is empty.

Comment: What is the output of running `top -n 1` on the shell? Keep in mind most Linux commands either do not exist or are totally broken in Android.

Comment: 'top -n 1' displays current cpu usage, memory usage and list of all processes running while executing from adb shell. Android do support top command. I successfully used it to find the cpu usage of the system in the same program.

Comment: Did you run as root or normal user? Try with normal user. And running the whole command on shell does create the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea to fill a file with the output. I would try to following

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("top -1 1");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream ());

// simple approach, omit some checkings, not compiled or tested, so may still fail
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter ("top.log");
for (int chr; (chr = reader.read ()) != –1;) {
  writer.append((char) chr);
}
writer.close()
```

However, it may be that android doesn't support "top", may be you need to apply the full path (on my ubuntu /usr/bin/top)

When you need the output into a file, put the content of reader into that file. ">" is a feature of the shell, not of exec